# Apache reverse proxy sometimes takes over all requests

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, websocket

I am using my apache as a reverse proxy for a few requests to a webserver running on an internal port to allow access via my regular virtual host. This is on an ubuntu 15 running in vagrant.

Here's my virtualhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /vagrant/htdocs
  ServerName test.vm

  # proxy pass mailcatcher to internal webserver
  <Location /mailcatcher>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:1080
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:1080
  </Location>
  <Location /assets>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:1080/assets
  </Location>
  <Location /messages>
    ProxyPass ws://localhost:1080/messages
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:1080
  </Location> 

  <Directory />
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /vagrant/htdocs>
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

For a while, this works fine. However, after a time, suddenly *all* requests to this virtualhost are proxied to the internal webserver. So if I call `http://test.vm/cron/mails.php` at first it will run `mails.php` as expected. However after a random amount of time or event, suddenly the aforementioned URL will start serving responses from [Mailcatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/).

> The message you were looking for does not exist, or doesn't have content of this type

This is a Mailcatcher error that you get when you request a message that no longer exists.

This service, Mailcatcher, is started with my VM and runs all the time. The weird thing is, I don't experience this issue when I am doing other stuff on the VM (there's a web app running on it). Only when I am actively debugging mails and using the Mailcatcher gui am a I suddenly sometimes experiencing this.

Waiting for a while or restarting apache "solves" this issue until it pops up the next time. Can anyone help me out on this? Did I set up my proxy wrong?

Thanks.